# How to capture server response time in JMeter in Badboy Software

Tags: jmeter, badboy

I wanted to capture the server response time. I select a variable from the dropdown from our panel then select the Date Range and then select download.

My question is when I select the "Download" and then server report is raedy, how to capture reports time by using badboy software. When I export this jmx script to JMeter it showing the status as a fail (red).

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture the response time for a single operation for a single user you don't need any extra software, the majority of modern browsers come with [Developer Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) which in their turn include network monitoring/profiling.

---

If you want to go for a some form of performance testing and plan to use JMeter for this - be aware that the chance of successfully replaying a recorded script is minimal as:

1. Most probably you do need to be [logged in](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#logging_in) in order to download the report, don't you?
2. Modern websites extensively use [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) for various reasons so make sure to add at least [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan
3. Most probably you cannot reach out to the report page directly, you need to navigate to it somehow and navigation steps can be protected from [CSRF attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

---

So basically you need to [replicate the real user using the real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) in order to succeed with JMeter script creation. It assumes that JMeter should produce the same network traffic pattern as real browser does. Use [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and inspect request (and response) details. The requests originated from JMeter and from the real browser must be exactly the same (apart from dynamic parameters which have to be [correlated](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start))